# Finding the package of a Detexify Symbol

Tags: symbols

I was simply messing around on a website called:
[Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)

just drawing various math symbols, when I came across a cool and interesting symbol of a fax machine. The following command for it being:  `\Faxmachine`

My question was, does anyone know what **package** is needed to be able to compile with the command in the tex file because I keep getting undefined control sequence.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org) always adds the necessary package to a symbol after presenting possible matches to what you have drawn. But you also can click on the „symbols“ button and enter the command. Here, too, the necessary package is added. So, in this case you will need the [marvosym](http://ctan.org/pkg/marvosym) package.

---

[image]

Comment: Thank You for the response. I should feel silly. I was so amazed when I seen a fax machine that I did not even notice the package dangling right above the command.

Comment: I got it to run, but I was trying to edit the size of the default by using \Large, or \Huge. They were not be enough. Is there a maximum size that this image can be or is there any other method of enlarging?

Comment: @night owl: These commands are only predefined [font sizes](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/info/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.html#Font-sizes). You can either try `\fontsize` as one of the [low-level font commands](ftp://ftp.tu-chemnitz.de/pub/tex/info/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.html#Low_002dlevel-font-commands) or play around with the `\scalebox` command from the [graphicx](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) package. If all comes to nothing, open a new question to receive more detailed answers.

Comment: Okay I will try those and hopefully it all works out well. Thanks.